# I have this code to find Prime numbers with in the range please anyone to tell why used i=2 in the nested loop?

Tags: c#

I know to change the value in nested for loop `i=2` the program will not give result in prime numbers. But I want to know the reason and purpose of assigning only `2` to `i`. Also a Plus if someone explain this using pseudo code.

```
using System;

namespace Prime_number
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num, i, count, start, end;

            Console.Write("Enter Start of range: ");
            start = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter End of range : ");
            end = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("The prime numbers between {0} and {1} are : \n", start, end);

            for (num = start; num <= end; num++)
            {
                count = 0;

                for (i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++)
                {
                    if (num % i == 0)
                    {
                        count++;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (count == 0 && num != 1)
                    Console.Write(num + "\n");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It starts at 2 because there's no point checking if the number is divisible by 1.

Comment: Side note: There's no point checking even numbers in that loop too, they are never going to be prime (apart from n=2)

Comment: If initial value of "i" is 0 or one code will not work for following reasons 1) If 0 : Would give divide by zero error 2) if 1 : The every value would be listed a Prime.  for example 4 % 1 = 0.

Comment: Side note: instead of an upper limit of num/2, a better one would be Math.Sqrt(num)

Comment: As for explaining the code: if you were given a number (say 35 or 37) how can you check whether it is prime? -> by checking whether it can be divided by any lower number (excluding 1). And you can stop checking way before "num-1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a self explanatory code:

> Read the `range_start` value.
> Read the `range_end` value.
> For each `value` from `range_start` to `range_end`
>
> > Check if `value`is divisible by any number in range `2` to the half of `value`
> > It will be prime if it is not divisible.

The divisors `0` and `1` are not tested for obvious reasons, all numbers are divisible by `1` and any number divided by `0` gives same result, infinity, in limits theory, or divide by zero exception, in a real CPU implementation. only numbers up to `value / 2` are tested for an also obvious reason, `value` would not be divisible by any number in that range but itself.

**EDIT:** As you're working with integer values, one small optimization would be to use `value >> 1` instead of `value / 2`, `shift` operations are way faster than `div` operations at CPU level, yet compilers often apply this optimization when the divisor is known at compile-time.